# PIC18F String to Bluetooth to Tera Term

Tags: bluetooth, embedded, pic

I am trying to output a string from the PIC's USART and have it display on Tera Term. I am using the:

- PIC18F4331
- Sparkfun Bluesmirf RN-42
- MPLAB v8.85
- Tera Term

I've been working at this code for a couple of days and I am not seeing a single response. A couple of things that I think may be causing the issue is the baud rate and/or not having an interrupt routine. But is there a need for an interrupt if I am only attempting to transmit? Please, can someone guide me? Also, when using printf, I am seeing a response through the bluetooth but in strange symbolic form. For example, þþþ.

The code is a modification of one found online.

```
// Libraries
#include <p18f4331.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Configuations 
#pragma config OSC      = XT
#pragma config WDTEN    = OFF  
#pragma config PWRTEN   = OFF 
#pragma config FCMEN    = OFF
#pragma config IESO     = OFF
#pragma config BOREN    = ON
#pragma config BORV     = 27
#pragma config WDPS     = 128
#pragma config T1OSCMX  = ON
#pragma config PWMPIN   = ON
#pragma config MCLRE    = ON
#pragma config LVP      = OFF
#pragma config STVREN   = OFF
#pragma config PWM4MX   = RD5

// Definitions
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000
#define BAUDRATE 9600


void EUSART(void)
{
    TRISC = 0b10000000;
    SPBRG = 25;
    TXSTAbits.CSRC = 0; // Baud Rate Generated Externally
    TXSTAbits.TX9 = 0; // 8-Bit Transmission
    TXSTAbits.TXEN = 1; // Transmit Enabled
    TXSTAbits.SYNC = 0; // Asynchronous Mode
    TXSTAbits.BRGH = 1; // High Baud Rate
    TXSTAbits.TRMT = 0; // Transmit Shift Register When TSR Is Full
    RCSTAbits.SPEN = 1; // Serial Port Enabled
    RCSTAbits.RX9 = 0; // 8-Bit Reception
    RCSTAbits.CREN = 1; // Enables Receive
}

void SendByteSerially(unsigned char Byte) // Writes a character to the serial port
{
    while(!PIR1bits.TXIF) ; // wait for previous transmission to finish
    TXREG = Byte;
}

unsigned char ReceiveByteSerially(void) // Reads a character from the serial port
{
    while(!PIR1bits.RCIF) continue;   // Wait for transmission to receive
    return RCREG;
}

void SendStringSerially(const rom unsigned char* st)
{
    while(*st) SendByteSerially(*st++);
}

void delayMS(unsigned int x)
{   
    unsigned char y;
        for(;x > 0; x--) for(y=0; y< 82;y++);
}

void main(void)
{
    unsigned char SerialData;
    EUSART(); 
    SendStringSerially("Hello World");

    while(1)
    {
        SerialData = ReceiveByteSerially();
        SendByteSerially(SerialData);
        delayMS(1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You are using a PIC18, be sure that BRG16 equals 0 since you're using BRGH**

```
BAUDCTL.BRG16 = 0;
```

because SPBRGH16 is the higher byte of SPBRG, and that may change the baudrate value of your USART.

Plus, be sure you're in the PIR1 bank. In MPLAB, that would be

```
banksel PIR1; //Not sure if there's an ending coma
```

My two functions to transmit via UART when properly initialized ( In MikroC ) :

```
void vTx232 (UC ucSend)
 {
    STATUS.RP0 = PIR1;     //Sure we're in PIR1
    while (PIR1.TXIF == 0);//While last TX not done
    TXREG = ucSend;        //Input param into TXREG
 }

void vTxString(UC *ucpString)
 {
   while (*ucpString!= 0x00)    //While string not at its end
    {
      vTx232(*ucpString);       //Send string character
      ucpString++;              //Increm string pointer
    }
 }
```